# How can I use input in grid view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to use a grid view. it contains a check box per row.

its for deleting row. for example when user checked some checkbooks and click on delete button checked rows have to delete.

Now How can I give checked rows ID's in my action ?

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: What king of grid you are using...? jqgrid? DataTables? raw html table...?

Comment: I used raw html table.

Answer (score 1):

OK. We assume that you want to retrieve a list of products and show them in a raw html grid.

First of all, arrange your view like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyPrj.Product>
// ... Other codes ...
<table id="tblGrid">
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>ProductName</th>
        // ... Other Properties ...
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="tr@(item.ProductID)">
            <td>
                @Html.Raw("<input type='checkbox' id='chk@(item.ProductID)' onclick='chkChange(@chkID)' />");        
            </td>
            <td>@item.ProductName</td>
            // ... Other Properties ...
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Selected Rows" onclick="performDelete()"/>
```

Now, you have your view and it will render the grid for you with the supplied model. Then, you need to add some javascript and jquery codes to perform the row deletion for you.

A function to handle checkbox clicks:

```
<script>
    function chkChange(id) {
        if ($(id).val() != 'false')
            $(id).val('false');
        else
            $(id).val('true');
    }

    // ...
</script>
```

And finally, a function to handle delete button clicks:

```
function performDelete() {
    var rows = $("input:checked");
    rows.each(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
}
```

That's it! - you're done. The complete `<script>` blog is like the following:

```
<script>
    function chkChange(id) {
        if ($(id).val() != 'false')
            $(id).val('false');
        else
            $(id).val('true');
    }

    function performDelete() {
        var rows = $("input:checked");
        rows.each(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the grid along with its checkboxes inside an HTML form and make the Delete button as submit button for this form. Then when the button is clicked, the form will be submitted and the values of the selected checkboxes will be sent to the controller action so that you could delete the corresponding records.